# Docker keeps on using old configuration from deleted container

Tags: docker

I am trying to configure Nginx but the config got missed up; so I attempted to re-create a new container; however, regardless of what I do. the new container comes up and has the old config of the old container.
here is my process of deleting old container and starting a new one.

```
 sudo docker container rm -f xxxx
    sudo docker system prune --volumes
    sudo docker system prune
    sudo systemctl stop docker
    sudo systemctl start docker
    sudo docker run --detach \
      --hostname xxx \
      --publish xxxxx \
      --name the same old name or new\
      --restart always \
      --volume xxxxx \
      xxx/xxx-xx:latest

sudo docker exec -it xxx /bin/bash
```

every folder and configuration I created before are still there. anything wrong I am doing?

Comment: What's that `--volume` option?  What are you actually changing in the configuration, and how?  What specific change are you not seeing undone?

Comment: everything I do under that container is persistence. e.g configuration/private/public keys. I learning the volume because I have used it in my setup so my guess was docker is keeping track of it.

Comment: Yes, if your nginx configuration is in that volume or bind mount, then you will get the same configuration even after you delete and recreate the container.

Comment: I deleted it the container and  prune --volumes why is it still there? how can I have a fresh start?

Answer (score 0):

Reason for that is the `--volume xxxxx` parameter. You should remove that volume, and create new one if that is what you need in your application:

```sh
docker rm -f container_name
docker volume rm -f volume_name
docker volume create new_volume
docker run --detach \
      --hostname xxx \
      --publish xxxxx \
      --name container_name \
      --restart always \
      --volume new_volume \
      xxx/xxx-xx:latest
```

Comment: Why do I need to create a new volume? if the volume is pruned as per documentation that data should be purged. it sounds like this is a bug to me. prune the volume only deletes the link to the memory location but doesn't delete the actual data. when I create a new container with the same volume I establish the link. if this is true that's security issue that is overlooked.... would like to hear other thoughts.

Comment: Command docker volume prune  remove all local volumes not used by any container. Any chance that this one did not go under that condition? Try removing it by name to be sure.